# Если в предложение напрашиваются много тире, как быть?

Tags: пунктуация

> Мороженое в мороженице (*но "мороженица" - это прибор?!* - это я
>   автору пишу. - **Прим. моё.**), кофе в кофейне – на какой-нибудь из площадей и
>   неторопливая прогулка в сторону дома, так выглядят послеобеденные
>   часы.

Привычное нам *кафе-мороженое* где-нибудь (на сленге?) называют *мороженицей*?

*Мороженое – в мороженице, кофе – в кофейне – на какой-нибудь из площадей – и неторопливая прогулка в сторону дома – так выглядят послеобеденные часы.*

Так "в идеале", но ТАК нельзя, - как же ж жить?

Comment: В Петербурге раньше исключительно этим словом называли заведения с надписью "Кафе-мороженое" - она казалась излишне канцелярской. В старом понимании, таких массово доступных и регулярно посещаемых заведений давно нет, потому и слово забылось.

Comment: Автор родом из Питера...

Comment: Ну, если худ. литература и ретро, то в самый раз :) Если же адаптировать, то в "кафе-морожен**ом**" - в кавычках, по вывеске.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Мороженое в "мороженице", кофе в кофейне на какой-нибудь из площадей и неторопливая прогулка в сторону дома – так выглядят послеобеденные часы.**

**Пояснение**

"Мороженицу" лучше заключить **в кавычки**, это сленговое (неофициальное) название.

**Примечание** (в Нацкорпусе нашлась мороженица)

Возле своего стола, как возле мойки **в мороженице**, как возле стойки бара ― как, впрочем, везде, ― Моньке вполне хватало места, чтобы, вращая ручку семейной мясорубки, сделать парочку «стильных» движений бедрами... [Марина Палей. Кабирия с Обводного канала (1990)]

Answer (score 2):

"Кафе-мороженица" можно найти в Интренете

[Кафе-кондитерские и мороженицы в Санкт-Петербурге](http://www.kidsreview.ru/spb/catalog/restorany-i-kafe/kafe-konditerskie-i-morozhenitsy-v-sankt-peterburge-spb)

“Отличеная мороженица!” [Отзыв](https://www.tripadvisor.ru/ShowUserReviews-g298484-d7153857-r336473135-Cafe_Gelateria_Plombir-Moscow_Central_Russia.html) о Кафе-джелатерия ПЛОМБИР

Однако читая "Мороженое - в мороженице" сразу представляешь машину для приготовления мороженого, а уже потом начинаешь гадать, что это. Так писать нехорошо.

Как вариант, убираем все необязательные тире о получаем спокойное повествование:

**Мороженое в кафе-мороженице, кофе в кофейне на какой-нибудь из площадей и неторопливая прогулка в сторону дома – так выглядят послеобеденные часы.**